# how to load progress when Angular change the page?

Tags: angular, frontend

When I change the page ,I home the web app shows the progress,when new page loaded finish,the pregress disappear,it looks like the picture below.
[image]

I have a way to realize the goal.
Create a service,then add `providers` in every page component.Secondly,implements `OnDestroy` and `OnAfterContentChecked`.In `ngOnDestroy`,inform the service start the progress,in `ngOnAfterContentChecked`,inform the service stop the progress.

But that's too troublesome.I think there has a better way to realize the target.Who can help me? Or recommand me a plugin.

Comment: A fully automatic loading bar with zero configuration for Angular app : https://github.com/aitboudad/ngx-loading-bar

Comment: You can subscribe to [router events](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events) at the root of your application. Every time a new `NavigationStart` event is fired show progress bar and then when the `NavigationEnd` event is fired hide progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    constructor(private router: Router, private ngZone: NgZone,
private renderer: Renderer,) {
        router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
          this._navigationInterceptor(event);
        });
      }
     private _navigationInterceptor(event: RouterEvent): void {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      // bypass change detection
      this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {

      });
    }
}
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {

    }

    if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {

    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationError) {

    }
    }
```